# Go to line number and extract text in following matching brackets

Tags: python, regex, bash, perl, text-extraction

After searching through previously asked questions. I need some  help in solving my problem. What I want to do could be in any language Bash, Perl, Python etc. I have just started Bash and Perl.

I read a text file and then I want to code a script that if I

- give line number.
- The script goes to that line number and sees the first bracket.
- Searches till it finds the matching bracket while ignoring nested ones and outputs all the text in between.

For e.g if there is the code.

**INPUT : I give line number(eg 60) as the input**

.
.
.

> //line number 60

```
      //convolving F

        j=0;
        while(j<N_sim)
    {
      Vect_F[j]=0;
      for (k=0; ((k<N_col) & ((j-k)>=0)); k++)
        Vect_F[j]+=F[i][k]*Vect_Up[j-k];
            j++;
    }

      //adding the results to the y matrix

      for (j=0; j < N_sim; j++)
    y[j]+=Vect_F[j];
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
      .     {
  Vect_F[j]=0;
  for (k=0; ((k<N_col) & ((j-k)>=0)); k++)
Vect_F[j]+=F[i][k]*Vect_Up[j-k];
          j++;
      .     }
```

What approach should I follow?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your text file and the desired output?

Comment: I think you need a .net solution as it supports balancing groups.

Comment: @stribizhev, It can be done a couple of ways using Perl regexp, and that's not counting Text::Balanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) extension module to check for the balancing of brackets.

```
import regex
m = input("Enter the line number:\n")
with open('file') as f:
    fil = f.readlines()[int(m)-1:]
    print(regex.search(r'{(?:(?0)|[^{}])*}', ''.join(fil)).group())
```

Example of how the above code works.

```
$ cat file
foo        
while(j<N_sim)
    {
      Vect_F[j]=0;
      for (k=0; ((k<N_col) & ((j-k)>=0)); k++)
        Vect_F[j]+=F[i][k]*Vect_Up[j-k];
            j++;
    }
$ python3 f.py
Enter the line number:
3
{
      Vect_F[j]=0;
      for (k=0; ((k<N_col) & ((j-k)>=0)); k++)
        Vect_F[j]+=F[i][k]*Vect_Up[j-k];
            j++;
    }
```

Comment: This works for balanced brackets but still would be fooled by `}` within strings etc. For flawless operation, one needs to write a parser for each possible language, alongside with a detection feature that will find out what the language in that file is.

Comment: What is `(?0)` in Python regexp? Looks like an expression, but I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Very true. And worse, what if the indicated starting line is inside a multiline comment? Really, not so simple a problem.

Comment: @rici if op ask these kind of questions to me, then i'll delete this answer. OR i'll try to improve my answer according to his needs :)